# Access database from a deployed Next Application

Tags: cloud, web-development-server, vercel

I'm new to web development and currently learning Next, my question is how will I be able to access the my database (PostgreSQL) once I've deployed my application (both from and back) to Vercel.

Is there anyway, or should I create an API prior to deployment that will generate a report for the contents of my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your database from your Vercel deployment the same way you access it from local development on your machine, by setting **Environment Variables**.

With Next.js, you can create a [`.env.local`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) file with names/values and use those with `next dev`.

With Vercel, you add those names/values to in the Project Settings under [Environment Variables](https://vercel.com/docs/environment-variables).